# Can you add the same hit as someone else?

Tags: phase-10

Can you add the same hit card as someone else did?

Suppose I'm playing with 4 people, it's my turn and I laid down my phase and then hit on a run of 4,5,6,7, ... I added an 8 and 9. The next player has her phase and wants to play the same hit that I just did. She wants to add an 8,9 and 10. I told her she can't add the 8 and 9, only the 10, because I already added the 8 and 9.

The rules say this:

> HITTING: Hitting is the way to get rid of leftover cards after making a Phase. You make a hit by putting a card directly on a Phase already laid down. The card must properly fit with the cards already down.
>
> EXAMPLES: You may add one or more “4s” to a player’s existing set of “4s.” You may add a “2” to a player’s existing run of “3”, “4”, “5”, “6”. You may also add a “7” and an “8” to this run, if you have them. You may add one or more green cards to a player’s seven green cards in Phase 8. You may also add a “Wild” card of any color to any of these card situations. Before you can make a hit, your own Phase must already be laid down. You may hit only during your turn. You may hit your own cards, another player’s cards, or both.

Answer (score 2):

**You were correct**

There's two key phrases in the Hit rule to support this,

> You make a hit by **putting a card directly on a Phase** already laid down. The card **must properly fit with the cards already down.**

The first phrase deals with your cards being added to the played Phase and not a separate "also could legally go here" pile. In effect, your card becomes part of the phase. This leads to the second part: since your card is now part of the Phase, a duplicate would not properly fit (at least in this example of a straight Phase).

Your opponent can still play the 10 because that will properly fit the run, and either of you could subsequently add a 3, or 11, etc.